# Continous function on compact interval - bounded

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $K$ be a compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Then every continous function $\phi :K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is **automatically** bounded.

Is this a consequence of; the image of a compact is compact ? It's just when the author is using the word "automatically" I'm being confused.

Comment: Compact sets are *automatically* bounded, so... yeah. :D

Comment: Yes ok. It's just that. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $\phi$ maps compact sets to compact sets, so its image is compact, and thus bounded, thus $\phi$ is bounded.